# Large-scale projected minimum-eigenvalue computations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues, numerical-linear-algebra

I am interested in efficient numerical procedures for solving large-scale instances of the following projected minimum-eigenvalue problem:

$$\mu := \min_{v \in \mbox{ker}(A)} \frac{v^T H v}{\lVert v \rVert^2}$$

where $H$ is a symmetric $n \times n$ matrix and $A$ is a (possibly rank-deficient) $m \times n$ matrix.  I am aware that $\mu$ can (in principle) be straightforwardly determined as:

$$\mu = \lambda_{\min}\left(Z^T H Z\right)$$

where $Z$ is a $n \times p$ matrix whose columns form an orthonormal basis for $\mbox{ker}(A)$; however, for my intended use case, matrices $H$ and $A$ are sufficiently large that performing an orthogonal decomposition of $A$ will be prohibitively expensive.  On the other hand, I assume that I can perform matrix-vector multiplications with each of these efficiently, and that I have available to me efficiently-computable preconditioning operators for $H$ and/or the block matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
H & A^T \\
A & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$,

and possibly $A$ as well.

Apologies if this is a somewhat trivial question: this seems like the kind of problem has likely been studied before, but I have not yet come across anything in the literature that seems to quite fit these constraints.  Any suggestions/pointers would be greatly appreciated!